# Write away parameter to text file

Tags: python

I have a simple method for which I have to do the following:

- Open a .txt file
- Add text to the file on a new line

Therefore I made the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path = '/test'
os.chdir(path)

def writeScores(test):
 with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    var = "\n", test, "\n"
    f.write(var)
```

This however gives me the following error. Any thoughts where I go wrong?

```
 TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: what is the datatype of test in your code? n how are you calling your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to concatinate the string, so use `+` instead of `,`

```
import pandas as pd
import os
#path = '/test'
#os.chdir(path)

def writeScores(test):
 with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    var = "\n" + test + "\n"
    f.write(var)

writeScores("asd")
```

Answer (score 2):

you're trying to write a `tuple` to your file.

While it would work for `print` since `print` knows how to print several arguments, `write` is more strict.

Just format your `var` properly.

```
var = "\n{}\n".format(test)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this error because your first argument is not string, you should pass it a string ,you can use this simple script and also you can change "rw" to "w+"
or use 'a+' for appending (not erasing existing content)

```
import os

writepath = 'some/path/to/file.txt'

mode = 'a' if os.path.exists(writepath) else 'w'
with open(writepath, mode) as f:
    f.write('Freeman Was Here!\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string you have created a tuple here with comma separated values like

```
var = "\n" + test + "\n"
```

So you can't write that tuple directly on the file.so lets put values inside that tuple to a string as:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fp:
    var = "\n", test, "\n"
    fp.write(''.join('%s' % x for x in var))
```

and the much better way is answered by @Jean-François Fabre